# transform list(character) to string in python

Tags: python

I am working on a python program in which i have to concatenate the characters in the list to make a string like ['h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o'] should be hello. I am using `for` loop to do this. I am searching for a built-in method that do this work. I searched but i didn't find any method.
My code is:

```
list=['h','e','l','l','o']
    s=""
    for i in list:
        s+=i
    print(s)
```

Comment: Use `''.join(list)`. BTW, making a variable named same as built-in functions shadows the built-ins. Use something like `l` or `my_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `join()` method :

```
s = "".join(list)
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
s = 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join():

```
print ''.join(list)
```